# PHP generate random shuffled sequence

Tags: php, arrays, random

I'm trying to generate a random array (if I'm using the term right), WITH possible duplicates but not next to each other, and out of a given array.

Ex with the variables: lions tigers bears monkeys elephants

I want to be able to produce one line, but with the possibilities of: "lions and tigers and bears" OR "bears and lions and monkeys and elephants" OR "monkeys and elephants" OR "elephants and lions and elephants and tigers"

So it would need to require a random number of possibilities (no less than two - so "bears and tigers" and any other product with two of the options would be the minimum - but also no more than seven.) And again, I would like the variables to be available to be duplicated, but not next to each other, so something like "monkeys and lions and tigers and monkeys" would be possible.

Since I don't know a lot about PHP, this is just one of the options I've tried:

```
<?php 
$input_array = array("lions", "tigers", "bears", "monkeys", "elephants");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
?>
```

But since it only generates a static amount of two elements and doesn't repeat, it doesn't quite produce what I'm trying to do.

Any help would be appreciated, especially if it includes code for putting the word "and" in between each variable, and also prints them (instead of generating the algorithm) - PHP is very new to me and I'm not sure how to do it without messing up.

Comment: Despite the few lines of code you provided this seems more like a request for code writing than a request on helping to fix code. Try some code where you generate a number between 2 and 7 and then loop over those input_array values that random many times

Comment: @RST: Thanks for the advice! I managed to get a better working code that covered what I was trying to do in the first place, but I still have an issue with repeating values now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input:

```
$input_array=["lions","tigers","bears","monkeys","elephants"];
```

Method:

```
$count=mt_rand(2,7);                  // declare number of elements to extract
echo "Count = $count\n";              // display expected element count

$result=[];
while(sizeof($result)<$count){        // iterate until count is fulfilled
    if(($new_val=$input_array[array_rand($input_array)])!=end($result)){
        $result[]=$new_val;           // add new value if different from previous value
    }
}
echo implode(' and  ',$result);       // display values (joined by ' and ')
```

Some Potential Outputs:

```
Count = 6
monkeys and tigers and bears and tigers and monkeys and bears

Count = 2
elephants and lions

Count = 7
lions and bears and lions and elephants and monkeys and elephants and lions
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much.

Comment: @pie  No worries.  Is everything clear regarding my method?  If you would like anything explained further just ask.

Comment: It makes sense - this will definitely be helpful to me in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

So what you wanna do is the following:

First you need to set how many shuffled elements there should be.

```
$num = rand(2,7); // get random number between 2 and 7
```

Then you iterate over your $input_array that many times. Also check if the last entry in it is equal to the new added, in that case, skip the iteration and roll the dice again.

```
$rand_keys = array();
while($num>0){ // repeat as long as $num is not zero
    $rand_key = $input_array[rand(0,count($input_array)-1)]; // select random key from input_array
    if(count($rand_keys)==0 || $rand_keys[count($rand_keys)-1]!=$rand_key){ // check if either this is the first element to add, or if the last element added is not equal to the new one
        $rand_keys[] = $rand_key; // push new key into rand_keys
        $num--;
    }
}
```

Now your $rand_keys array should contain the desired shuffled keys.

PS: to turn this array into a string like in your example use `implode(' and ',$rand_keys);`

Comment: There is no need to do all the counting. Input_array is not changed so there is no need to count on every iteration. There is no need to count the rand_keys array either because you can track the same info by using $num.

Comment: @ManuelOtto Thanks! I actually managed to get the generator (I edited my question) and tried to put in what you did for checking for duplicates, but it didn't quite work, if you wanted to look at that.